# Database events with JayData

Tags: javascript, events, knockout.js, jaydata

Is there a way to register for events or receive any other kinds of notifications when EntitySet is changed in any way? (objects updated, inserted, deleted, etc)

I want Knockout to listen for these changes and be able to update EntitySet from external script which has nothing to do with UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JayData Entity Notifications API will be released with JayData 1.2 in August. We will also release an AJAX/HTML5 notification service you can build upon and also tools to implement notifications over WCF 5.0 Data Services. (Local services like webSql and IndexedDB will get notification support earlier with 1.1.5 at end of July)
BTW: what provider are you using?

Up to the current version (1.1) EntitySets represent only "static ports" for querying data. Query results are static arrays, totally disconnected from the data context. In JayData 1.0.4 we released support for Knockoutjs observableArrays as valid query result holders and with 1.0.5 we got JSLQ Dynamic Queryies with  Knockoutjs observable parameters. JayData 1.1 was mostly about OData V3 new features and JayData 1.2 will be all about multiuser access and realtime collaboration over data and thus notifications in the center:)

Comment: Well, the roadmap looks awesome, I really appreciate the work you do on JayData! The things I work on can probably wait until August so I will not write any hacks until then and wait for your proper release :)

Comment: The code regarding these might be ready prior August. Follow github.com/jaydata to get notification on the new checkins and releases. Thank you for your nice words :)